# Using awk to extract specific "words" with different types of patterns (and possible duplicate entries) and create a new tab delimited file

Tags: awk, fasta

I have many [fasta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) files in which I have to extract information from the "header" lines.

Input file

```
>12321:Chr13 923456-923659(3C->A)|Chr14 463456-463669(4T->A)
AGCTAAAAAATGCGATG
>50:Chr1 495831-495959
TGCGATTATGCGATTATGCGAT
>5891:Chr13 363456-573659(3T->A)|Chr13 363456-573659(3T->A)|Chr14 463456-463669(4A->T)
AATATGCGATGAGCTAAG
>893:Chr21 139656-139690(3C->A)|Chr14 149656-149690(4T->A)
TGCTATGAGCTAATAAAAAATGCGATG
```

Output file (this is the expected output) 
for each Chr per line, we get coordinates and the number after ">" but when there is a possible duplicate (inside the same line) then we have to exclude it. Whatever is inside the parenthesis isn't used.

```
Chr13  923456 923659    12321
Chr14  463456 463669    12321
Chr1   495831 495959    50
Chr13  363456 573659    5891
Chr14  463456 463669    5891
Chr21  139656 139690    893
Chr14  149656 149690    893
```

I used :

```
egrep ^[\>] file1.fas > file1_head.fas
```

to extract only header lines.
and then:

```
 awk -F: '/\>/ {n=split($2,s,"|");for(i=0; i<n; ++i) print $1 "\t" s[i] }' file1_head.fas > new.txt
```

Current output:

```
>12321
>12321  Chr13 923456-923659(3C->A)
>50
>5891
>5891   Chr13 363456-573659(3T->A)
>5891   Chr13 363456-573659(3T->A)
>893
>893    Chr21 139656-139690(3C->A)
>353
>353    Chr13 363456-573659(3T->A)
>353    Chr13 363456-573659(3T->A)
```

Issues:

- In some lines, there aren't any | and probably that causes the first problem with the output (not printing the 2nd column)
- How should I keep only one entry in case of duplicates/triplicates/...

What I expect to do is take for each Chr* plus the coordinates and the number so as to have a [bed](https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1)-like file format

Thank you in advance

A part from "real" file: https://jpst.it/1tSMN

## New Example

```
>25828:Chr15 99785054-99806017|Chr15 99785054-99806017|Chr15 101748003-101785983|Chr15 101748003-101785983|Chr15 101748003-101785983 
TCTGAGAAGATGAACTCCTTGGTCTGCCT 
>24578:Chr15 62204018-62281012|Chr15 62204018-62281012 
TTCAGTTTGAATCTAAGGAGCC 
>2439:Chr15 99785054-99806017|Chr15 99785054-99806017|Chr15 101748003-101785983 
TCTGAGAAGATGAACTCCTTGGTCTG
>1:KI270734.1 70016-79001(19T->C)
CGCGGGTGTATGCCAT
>2:GL000224.1 117026-129966(3T->G)
TCCCGAATCGGA
```

Expected output:

```
Chr15 99785054 99806017 25828 
Chr15 101748003 101785983 25828 
Chr15 62204018 62281012 24578 
Chr15 99785054 99806017 2439
Chr15 101748003 101785983 2439
KI270734.1 70016 79001 1
GL000224.1 117026 129966 2
```

Comment: Your sample Input_file and expected output doesn't match, could you please check it once if they are either fine if NO then correct it else let us know logic behind getting it please.

Comment: Your output is different from the accepted answer output, which one is the expected one ?

Comment: @KGeles, my answer is updated after your question is edited, I hope it is giving same output now, please confirm once.

Comment: @KGeles I edited my answer to fit your new specifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F':' '/>/{gsub(/\|/, RS NR FS $1 FS); print NR FS $0}' file1_head.fas | awk -F'[->:( ]' '{key = $1 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6}!s[key]{s[key] = 1; print $4, $5, $6, $3}'
```

Returns :

```
Chr13 923456 923659 12321
Chr14 463456 463669 12321
Chr1 495831 495959 50
Chr13 363456 573659 5891
Chr14 463456 463669 5891
Chr21 139656 139690 893
Chr14 149656 149690 893
```

**EDIT** on second example :

Returns :

```
Chr15 99785054 99806017 25828
Chr15 101748003 101785983 25828
Chr15 62204018 62281012 24578
Chr15 99785054 99806017 2439
Chr15 101748003 101785983 2439
KI270734.1 70016 79001 1
GL000224.1 117026 129966 2
```

Comment: Let me disagree, I think it is proper to split the command in two defined steps.

Comment: First step : clean the data file to get similar lines, second step : extract the informations you want

Comment: I cannot use sort -u because I need entries from different lines.
All these problems arise from that you can have 2 different kinds of duplicates.
  1)  duplicate entry coordinates in the same line (not useful)
  2)  duplicate entry coordinates in a different line (useful for further analysis)

Comment: @KGeles I think that you can use `sort -u`. I don't do it on your input file, I do it on a fixed version where one line = one entry

Comment: @KGeles I don't have access to drive, I can help only if you explain what is wrong

Comment: Yes and that's why we cannot use it like that. Because If we first split each line then how could we separate not useful duplicates from useful?

Comment: @KGeles using the id before `:`

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an id but a "count" number that could be the same for many entries.

Is the number of times that particular sequence found mapping to a reference genome.

Comment: @KGeles edited. I use the line number to manage duplicates correctly

Comment: Another issue with `sort -u` is that I cannot confirm if the output is correct. The lines are sorted regarding line number how I'm going to verify that everything is ok?

Comment: @KGeles edited again, it's ok if we don't use `sort`, it was just an idea to preserve your memory

Comment: I checked it in different files and seems that there aren't any more issues. If you have a GitHub account please share the code in order to credit you.

Comment: I don't understand why? Both of you #Corentin #RavinderSingh13 spend a lot of time to help.

Comment: @KGeles a subtil combination of boredom, stubborness and willing to improve make me spend time to answer (I learnt new things from RavinderSingh13's answer and EdMorton's comment). Credit does not help me making progress, but it's nice that you suggested it.

Comment: @KGeles, I am really confuse in requirements, will try to complete it. But I am always with going for correct answer always for OP, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 you need to remove duplicates only if they appear on the same line. The key I use to remove duplicates is : line number, name (`Chr13` for example) and values (`923456-923659` for example). Things in parenthesis (`(3C->A)`) don't count. I don't consider elements that have a key i've considered before.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT2:*** Since OP mentioned `chr` string could not be there sometimes so adding logic to get any kind of strings output.

```
awk -F"[:|]" '
/^>/ !e[$0]++{
  sub(/>/,"",$1)
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
      num=split($i,array,"[- (]")
      if(!b[array[1]"("array[num-1]array[num]]++){
        print array[1],array[2],array[3],$1
      }
    delete array
  }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Since OP asked about complete lines can be duplicate so to take care of those could try following.

```
awk -F"[:|]" '
/^>/ !e[$0]++{
  sub(/>/,"",$1)
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /Chr/){
      num=split($i,array,"[- (]")
      if(!b[array[1]"("array[num-1]array[num]]++){
        print array[1],array[2],array[3],$1
      }
    delete array
    }
  }
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***1st Solution:*** Considering that you need index of elements eg--> `Chr13,(3C->A)` etc.
Could you please try following.

```
awk -F"[:|]" '
/^>/{
  sub(/>/,"",$1)
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /Chr/){
      num=split($i,array,"[- (]")
      if(!b[array[1]"("array[num-1]array[num]]++){
        print array[1],array[2],array[3],$1
      }
    delete array
    }
  }
}'    Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Chr13 923456 923659 12321
Chr14 463456 463669 12321
Chr1 495831 495959 50
Chr13 363456 573659 5891
Chr14 463456 463669 5891
Chr21 139656 139690 893
```

---

---

***2nd Solution:*** Considering that you need to make index of eg--> `Chr13,363456,573659` ten do following.

```
awk -F"[>:|]" '                                      ##Setting field separator as either > or : or | for all lines for Input_file.
NF>1 && /^>/{                                        ##Checking condition if NF>1 and line starts from > then do following.
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){                                ##Starting a for loop from i=3 to value of NF in current line.
    if($i ~ /Chr/){                                  ##checking condition if field value is Chr string then only do further things.
      split($i,array,"[- (]")                        ##Using split function to split current field value into array named array and field separators as - or space or (
      val=array[1] OFS array[2] OFS array[3]         ##Creating variable val whose value is arrays 1,2 and 3 values with OFS values in between them.
      delete array                                   ##Deleting this array for safer side so it shouldnot print previous values wrongly.
    }
    if(!a[val]++ && val){                            ##For removing duplicates checking if array a index with val is there or not and val is NOT NULL then do following
      print val,$2                                   ##Printing variable val,$2 here.
    }
    val=""                                           ##Nullifying variable val here.
  }
}' Input_file                                        ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I agree that OP is not clear, but your output file is different. You need to use the Chr<number> and (<smth>-><smth>) information to drop duplicates

Comment: For example, you shouln'd print `Chr14 149656 149690 893` because `Chr14 (4T->A)` was already used in line `Chr14 463456 463669 12321`

Comment: @KGeles of course both scripts return different output. On your exemple my solution returns your expected output, this script does not

Comment: @KGeles, please try my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: @KGeles, my new code expect that complete line(s) duplication, so make sure we both are on same page, I tried with some dummy lines from your given samples and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @KGeles, in comments it is not clear, please post in your thread in code tags and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Ok there are also entries with different names except "chr".

Comment: @KGeles, could you please check my EDIT2 and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Excuse me for not being clear,  the 1st Edit is not relative to the question. There aren't any duplicate lines.

Comment: @KGeles, ok np, could you please check EDIT2, it is working as expected I believe, let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 In first file, `Chr14  149656 149690    893` is missing. In second file, you have duplicates and `Chr15 101748003 101785983 2439` is missing

Comment: @CorentinLimier, since I thought I need to remove duplicates.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Edit2 doesn't work correctly in the true file

Comment: @KGeles, I can't access that file from office, will go home and try it out, what's not working actualy?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Some entries from the same line are not printed and the problem with the true file still exists.